# Getting value from mysql array with same column names

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * 
    FROM companies 
    LEFT JOIN (ownership_reseller_to_company, users) 
    ON (users.ID=ownership_reseller_to_company.RESELLER_ID AND ownership_reseller_to_company.COMPANY_ID=companies.ID) 
    WHERE companies.NAME LIKE '%".$search_parm."%' AND users.ID='".$_USERID."'
```

My issue is I have NAME under `companies` and NAME under `users` but when I use `$row['NAME'];` I get the NAME under `users`. Is there a way to get the one under `companies`? I have tried $row['companies.NAME'] but with no success.

Comment: Maybe give them separate aliases ?

Comment: You will have to alter the `SELECT` statement and use separate aliases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use alias because column name is same in both table.

**Example:**

```
SELECT companies.name as cName, users.name as uName FROM companies .......
```

**Than use like:**

```
$row['cName'] // company name
$row['uName'] // user name
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know you could do aliases in MySQL.

Comment: Alias use as alternate name in yur mysql query @frank-thornton

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `PDO` you can:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, 1);
```

from the docs (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php):

> Prepend the containing table name to each column name returned in the result set. The table name and column name are separated by a decimal (.) character. Support of this attribute is at the driver level; it may not be supported by your driver.

Comment: Vote for PDO suggestion ... :)

Comment: @devpro thanks, `PDO` is the best database extension for PHP for offering settings like this one, imho ;)